# How do I create "internal Outlinks" for a better SEO?

Tags: seo

I was searching on the web after I analyzed the link structure of Yoast. There he uses links to redirect users to a different page.

Here a example:

https://yoast.com/out/synthesis/

Can someone tell me what this is called, or how I create such links as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually really simple.  He isn't using it for SEO purposes since it's just a 301 redirect.  He is purposefully hiding the affiliate url AND adding 'onclick' Google Analytics tracking to the link.  Also - the "/out/" directory is being blocked by robots.txt and then redirect's back to the index page.

To answer your question:
This is not for SEO reasons.  He is using it for both tracking click and hiding his affiliate link/url.

Answer (score 0):

These are called internal links, when you link to you one of your domain or subdomain pages. Internal links adds values for SEO as it makes the crawlers aware of those existing pages. There are many options for generating internal links. It depends on your page structure etc. Some of the common options are by using **html sitemap** like trip advisor's does, using **header and footer**. For html sitemaps, go to **http://www.tripadvisor.com/**, scroll all the way bottom to the footer section. There you can sitemap link, which is a path way for many internal links.

Comment: Ok I already know about Internal links and sitemaps... but in this case there is a redirection, which is used by yoast.com... how can I make it the same way when using wordpress?

Comment: which redirection are you talking abt?